# Pact Matcher - How to use "each like" for an array of arrays values

Tags: pact

I came across the below example for each like in Pact Matcher:

```
withBody {
        permissions eachLike(3, regexp(~/\w+/))
        permissions2 minLike(2, 3, integer())
        permissions3 maxLike(4, 3, ~/\d+/)
}
```

which is used to represent 'permissions' as value of arrays.

But I'm trying to use pact matcher for an array of arrays. 
Assume, if my response body will be like:

```
withBody {
[[id regexp('[0-9a-f]{8}','e8cda07e')
  name regexp(~/\w+/,'sony')], 
 [id regexp('[0-9a-f]{8}','e8cda07e')
  name regexp(~/\w+/,'sony')], 
 [id regexp('[0-9a-f]{8}','e8cda07e')
  name regexp(~/\w+/,'sony')]] 
}
```

Will 'each like' can be applicable for this case ? If yes, please provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

`eachLike` in the Groovy DSL only supports arrays of objects. If you use the Java DSL, there is a `eachArrayLike` method that can help you.